# amqp exchanges are not auto-deleted

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have rabbitmq 3.3.5 running and nodejs project based on amqplib 0.2.1

The problem is that once exchange has been asserted it does not deleted after connection to rabbitmq is closed.

If we start such example

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');
var when = require('when');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function(conn) {
  return when(conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {
    var ex = 'logs_new';
    var ok = ch.assertExchange(ex, 'fanout', {durable: false, autoDelete: true}})

    var message = process.argv.slice(2).join(' ') ||
      'info: Hello World!';

    return ok.then(function() {
      ch.publish(ex, '', new Buffer(message));
      console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", message);
      return ch.close();
    });
  })).ensure(function() { conn.close(); });
}).then(null, console.warn);
```

and run

```
#rabbitmqctl list_exchanges
```

Listing exchanges ...

```
amq.rabbitmq.log        topic
amq.rabbitmq.trace      topic
amq.topic       topic
logs_new    fanout
...done.
```

Though connection to rabbitmq was closed, but exchange (logs_new) still persists.

**How to tell rabbitmq that exchange needs to be deleted if it is not used by any connection ?**

edit: 
As it is stated at http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/doc/channel_api.html autoDelete option should be 'true'. but nevertheless even exchange with new name is not deleted. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You should set the `auto_delete` flag to `True` when declaring the exchange. This will automatically delete the exchange when all channels are done with it.

Keep in mind that this means that it will stay as long as there is an active binding to the exchange. If you delete the binding, or queue, the exchange will be deleted.

If you need to keep the queue, but not the exchange you can remove the binding once you are done publishing. This should automatically remove the exchange.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't write that autoDelete option was set to true. Still, does not help. What could be wrong? Exchange is new and has nothing binded to it.

Comment: Basically you need to add a binding to it before it gets removed. You can try this by adding an exchange in the management module, adding a binding to the exchange, and then when you then remove the binding, the exchange will be removed instantly.

Comment: It's probably easiest if you expand on the reasoning behind why you need the exchange deleted. Maybe we can suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks, binging and unbindng helps, but.. What if I have thousands of exchanges and some of them should be deleted in case they are not used at this moment? Should they persist until someone binds and unbinds to them? That does not seem very good.

Comment: I think that exchanges were not designed to be as disposable as queues. It would probably be easier to simply delete the exchange if it is no longer needed. Is there a reason why you need so many exchanges?

Comment: I have app that 1) have 10k message producers. 2) big amount of message receivers. Every message_produceer creates it's own exchange and pushes messages. message_receivers connects bind to 0-N exchanges and receives messages.        Sometimes message_producer connects and creates exchange and disconnect, but no one binds to it for long time. In this case exchange remains not deleted.

Comment: May be i should use one 'topic' exchange instead of lots exchanges for every message_producers? Is it recommended to use one high-loaded exchange inspite of lots low-loaded?

Comment: topics are a better alternative. Performance is pretty simple with RabbitMQ. Each queue is limited to one CPU, so as long as you spread it over multiple queues you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I will try one topic exchange for everything